Integrate a GETX Flutter app in to another GETX flutter app
I have a bigger app named X and I have another smaller one named Y. they are right now separate from each other and they are working fine. I want to integrate app Y in X. I want to put codes of Y in X project but they should have a different Main so I can set different themes and routes. Is there anyway to do that? I am using GetMaterialApp from GetX instead of MaterialApp. I want that if I click a button on app X then I navigate to Y app section as a screen or page. I have done code merging eg controlllers, models, data etc. Now I have main.dart files from both apps. Please help !!!
I tried making app Y a package but realised that would not work out. I tried navigating directly to MyApp() of app Y on click but that also did not work as initialisation was not possible. I then tried navigating to Y but after initialisation but then I got no errors and nothing happened. The screen did not change to Y part.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
